# SSIS Failed to retrieve long data for column XXXX

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package (SQL 2017) that is importing data from an Access database to SQL Database.

It errors out with the following error:

```
[Source - MaintenanceDetails [140]] Error: Failed to retrieve long data for column "JobNotes".
[Source - MaintenanceDetails [140]] Error: There was an error with Source - MaintenanceDetails.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output] on Source - MaintenanceDetails. The column status returned was: "DBSTATUS_UNAVAILABLE".
[Source - MaintenanceDetails [140]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Source - MaintenanceDetails.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output]" failed because error code 0xC0209071 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Source - MaintenanceDetails" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - MaintenanceDetails returned error code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

I've tried the following to resolve this based off other Stackoverflow questions which hasn't fixed the problem:

1) Setting a path for "BLOBTempStoragePath" and "BufferTempStoragePath"

2) Setting AutoAdjustBufferSize to False

3) Creating an Error Output to put failed errors into another tab

4) Setting "TypeGuessRows" to 0 for "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel"

5) I have tried using the Import/Export Wizard within Management Studio and I get the same error message.

The Connections are using:

Native OLE DB\Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider

Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Does anyone have any other suggestions for what I could try to resolve this?

Comment: When everything else fails, try exporting to flatfile first and import the flatfile with SSIS. This will exclude any connection specific errors. If the errors are still thrown you can be pretty sure it will be the data which is causing it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ppijnenburg. I can successfully export from Access to a text file using the Export wizard inside Access.

When I try and use that text within SSIS I get:

[Flat File Source [56]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "JobNotes" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was as ppijnenburg described. Once I exported the Access table to a comma separated TEXT file, SSIS had no issue dealing with it at all.

I suppose the moral of the story is importing from Access to SQL Server is messy.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem with that at Destination Editor on Error Output step I returned Error column to "Ignore Failure"

[image]